# Request to participate in a survey based on Stack Overflow contribution

Tags: discussion

I was surprised to see a mail in my inbox, which was requesting to participate in a survey and also said that, **You was chosen because your relevant participation/contribution in Stack Overflow - https://stackoverflow.com/.** The sender was **Vagner Clementino - vagnercs@dcc.ufmg.br** and I feel this as suspicious by seeing the email ID. Could this be possible? I mean, does Stack Overflow have anything to take care of this? Or this is simply just ignorable?

Below is what mail contents actually looks like.

> Dear Guruprasad Rao!
>
> I’m Vagner Clementino (homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~vagnercs), Master
>   Student at Federal University of Minas Gerais, Brazil. I’m conducting
>   a research, supervised by Prof. Rodolfo Resende -
>   homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~rodolfo concerned with improvements in Issue
>   Tracking System. As part of them, we planned and executed a survey
>   aiming at to reach a large-scale population of
>   researchers/practitioners interested on to improve the features of the
>   Issue Tracking Systems. Based on your area of interest, we kindly
>   invite you to take part in the following survey:
>
> //A goo.gl URL here
>
> You was chosen because your relevant participation/contribution in
>   Stack Overflow - https://stackoverflow.com/. Your opinion is essential
>   to strength our findings. Please, help us accordingly your
>   possibilities by answering this survey until January 29th. As soon as
>   we conclude data analysis, we will share the results with all
>   participants and the software engineering community. If you have
>   already fulfilled this questionnaire, please ignore this email.
>
> Thanks in advance, Vagner Clementino

This is the Survey Link which I was redirected to.

**http://www.surveygizmo.com/s3/3313110/Stack-Overflow-Understanding-and-Improving-the-Features-of-the-Change-Request-Management-Systems-copy**

Comment: What do you expect us to do about this? It's a survey solicitation that you can either do or ignore. But you have to expect to get stuff like this when you leave your email address in your public profile...

Comment: Federal University of Minas Gerais (in Portuguese: Universidade Federal de Minas Gerais, or UFMG for short) is an actual university which is well known in Brazil, and the contents of the mentioned *.ufmg.br pages match the description in the email.

Comment: @animuson I don't expect you guys to do anything but I just needed some info/clarification regarding this which **BoltClock** has given. Thanks much.

Comment: @duplode Oh I see. Never knew about this,, Thanks much for sharing..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao You should clarify your question then, because you explicitly ask "does SO have anything to take care of this?" And never mention anything about wondering whether it's affiliated with us (you should never assume something that wasn't sent from us is affiliated with us).

Comment: @animuson Its my bad that I couldn't frame it well with proper words, but what I actually meant was whether SO has some affiliation with this program or vice versa.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That survey, and whoever made it, is not affiliated with Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is not responsible for and has no control over the content of the survey.

Make of this what you will:

- If you're uncomfortable with the idea of taking surveys that aren't officially from Stack Overflow, you don't have to.
- If you're OK with taking unofficial surveys, do so knowing that they're unofficial.

Comment: I agree that I have left my email public so that I could help others. But I just wanted to know if it is affiliated with SO somehow. I got what you said I will decide to take on it or not. Thanks for the clarification..