# Did someone use Stack Overflow data in a bad way?

Tags: discussion, personal-data

I got a strange spam in my spams today (NB: link is incomplete and names removed *on purpose*):

[image: The spam]

What puzzles me is how is my Stack Overflow username linked by Osaka University to my email? Do Stack Exchange share its user base for research purposes??

Did anyone get a similar mail?

Comment: I don't think SO is even allowed to share private user data with external entities even if they wanted to do so (which I'm pretty sure they don't.) It seems very unlikely that a University would use illegally acquired private data, so the more likely explanation is that they found your E-Mail address by looking you up on the Internet. Is that a possibility?

Comment: @Pekka웃 You assume that a spam email is actually from a University...

Comment: @Servy good point, although this is very much in keeping with similar surveys I've received from verifiable University-affiliated projects. Still, could be an ingenious phishing angle asking for Google credentials behind a fake Google Docs link.

Comment: No - SE **never** discloses your private information to other parties and especially not for marketing purposes. Interestingly I've just had a quick peek at your email address you have registered (because normally it's not a hard task with some user names to take a wild stab at a contact email) but yours I never would have guessed. You do however mention some information in your profile page about where you work which could be cross-referenced I guess, but no - it wouldn't have come from SE.

Comment: I'm trying to find a post on MSE from the Director of Communities, Jon Ericson, which has much more detailed information, give me a mo...

Comment: All things considered, you *do* provide a link to your GitHub account, and one of your commits *does* have your real email address.  I genuinely doubt that Stack Overflow released that kind of information - they may have been able to infer that you use SO - and they used your use of SO to get to information that could be used to contact you.

Comment: @Makoto yup - that'd be it then.

Comment: Anyway - for now - there's https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy - see the *How We Use Information We Collect* section and the *Information You Choose to Display Publicly on the Network* - which is how from your profile @Makoto was able to find your email from a commit message.

Comment: I've dragged a university research team to their ethical review board because they scraped GitHub emails to contact GitHub users for their research. They can't ethically do it, but technically there is nothing stopping them from extracting email addresses from repositories. You have a GitHub account linked, I'm sure they could have made the link there, scraped your email from your commits, and so build a database.

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341939/1007939

Comment: @Makoto nice catch, I didn't thought about that.. I did ask mainly because of the *research aspect*. Will read Jon links. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Could they have scraped data from an old data dump?

Comment: Keep in mind that if they get your email address from somewhere else, it's fairly easy for them to connect your Stack Overflow account back to that email. While we don't publish email hashes anymore, we used to publish them in old data dumps to allow for accessing Gravatars for each user. So if they *already know* your email, they can simply run it through the same hashing algorithm and then match it to a user in an old dump, or any existing user that still uses Gravatar (the non-Identicon version, which uses IP instead) by just scraping images from the Users page.

Comment: this message looks pretty legit to me. why do you assume it is spam?

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin If you go by the literal definition, spam is any message that is unsolicited. OP didn't ask for the message, therefore it's spam. It can be a legit email while still being spam.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin yes the email seems legit, but I never gave Osaka university my email nor did I tell them I'm ok to participate in some study, so it's a spam ;)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm curious; what's unethical about reading an email address that someone personally put on the World Wide Web and using it to contact them?

Comment: @patricksweeney: In the case of email spam, the "literal definition" as you put it requires that the email be sent indiscriminately in bulk. That doesn't really seem to be the case here.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I'm wondering this too. It's publicly available, surely the idea is that you can contact the person?

Comment: @RobertMc: Indeed.

Comment: @RobertMc is your phone number public? Can I call you to talk to you about our savior or some new windows I sell? I'm pretty sure the answer is no. It's the same about email IMHO.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: see [Ethics of scraping "public" data sources to obtain email addresses](//academia.stackexchange.com/q/56598) and https://c.ymcdn.com/sites/www.casro.org/resource/resmgr/casro_code_of_standards.pdf, which cover US research organisations recruiting research subjects; the Academia.SE link shows that scraping GitHub repositories for email addresses breaks the stated Code.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: not mentioned in the Academia.SE post but present in the PDF: *Research Organizations are prohibited from using any subterfuge in obtaining email addresses of potential respondents, **such as collecting email addresses from public domains**, using technologies
or techniques to collect email addresses without individuals’ awareness, and collecting email addresses under the guise of some other activity.* (bold emphasis mine).

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: so reading my email address in a GitHub repository is fine, but then using it to contact me about some research you are doing is not, hence my complaint to the ethics board (it was the second time that research team contacted me about this that I sent it to the ethics committee, the first time I told the research team that they were crossing a line directly).

Comment: @RC no, my phone number is not public, for the precise reason that I don't want people calling me. Making it public, *as is the case with the email address we're talking about*, would leave me open to hearing about the saviour or some presumably wonderful new windows.

Comment: @RobertMc I see, in here when you open a line it's published and you have to opt-out. (and if the number of yours ending with 13 is not professional then it's public).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Bizarre. Yet another example, it seems, of "everything's always somebody else's fault" that is plaguing our modern society.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition there's also a "feature" of github that if you set your email to private but don't _also_ set another option someplace else in the profile settings, then commits/actions you make directly via the web interface will be signed with your real (private) email address. And this is not evident if you're only using the web interface, since commits don't have email addresses attached to them (at least I haven't found them yet). However if you clone someone's repo (including github gists), you'll see their email. Took me a while to notice and explicitly disable this "feature".

Comment: In case you're wondering, I guess my point is mostly that github aren't exactly bending over backwards to protect their users' data, so in the case of github I wouldn't be so quick to assume that privacy violations can only be the fault of users allowing too much. And even if users are stupid, abusing the folly of others might still be unethical.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the ethics point is very interesting ... I _have_ received emails from people who wanted to ask me something related to their research, but they were always informal. To what extent does "Hi I hope you don't mind, I found your email from github because you seem to be an expert in X and Y, I was hoping you could help me" violate the same ethics code as "Dear sir, we are a group researching X, please consider answering the questions in this survey". The former doesn't quite sound much different from emailing the author of a paper to ask things related to the paper or their field.

Comment: @MartijnPieters then again, as most academics, I've received _countless_ spam inviting me to be a speaker / chairperson for potentially inappropriate or virtually inexistent conferences, so, there's that ...

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou don't miss out on this opportunity to be an invited speaker at Convincing Sounding Conference 2018! It'll only cost you a measly 5k dollars. Edit just to be a bit on topic: I don't think Martijn has issues with your first example; informal directed communcation should be fine. Mass gathering and use of contact details irrespective of a person's specific work is what's problematic.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Hah, yes exactly. Actually, this is a good point though, emails of the conference kind have a potential scam incentive. The one in this post seems to be a simple survey to get research data, but they decided to completely impersonalise their approach. Ironically, I wouldn't be surprised if the standardised and formal nature of the email is _because_ some ethics committee got involved, rather than _despite_ it.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: it's a built-in 'vulnerability' of git (and mercurial and svn); the primary author identifier is the email address. GitHub is not special or wrong here, it is baked into the design of the version control system. [Any of these services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_source_code_hosting_facilities) will have the same issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what I consider to be a vulnerability is that there's a separate setting in the profile that lets me alias my web actions to `username@users.noreply.github.com`, and I would expect that to be automatically used. Or at least automatically enabled if I choose for my email address to be private.

Comment: @AndrasDeak this has to be set in your local git instance. `git config user.email username@users.noreply.github.com` in your local repo (add `--global` to have it apply machine-wide to all local repos). GitHub cannot change the commits you send to them post hoc because that'd change their hashes. The email is burned into the commit at commit time, and commits are immutable; there's nothing GitHub can do about it, other than perhaps recommending you not to configure git with a real email address.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I'm talking about commits made via the web interface, and [the corresponding setting in the profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0t5u.png). If you don't have this set, and create for instance a gist via web, then `git clone` it in terminal, you'll see your private email address in the log. Of course if you're committing from the terminal, you're in control. But if you're using the web interface, this needs to be set, otherwise your email address is leaking. It's akin to having a "kick me" sign on your back: you only notice once someone asks you whether you want it there.

Comment: @Andras Ow, that sucks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[Makoto's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350023/did-someone-use-stack-overflow-data-in-a-bad-way?cb=1#comment477859_350023) & [Martijn Pieters'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350023/did-someone-use-stack-overflow-data-in-a-bad-way?cb=1#comment477887_350023) answers seem to be the best from what we can tell about the other party:

> All things considered, you do provide a link to your GitHub account, and one of your commits does have your real email address. I genuinely doubt that Stack Overflow released that kind of information - they may have been able to infer that you use SO - and they used your use of SO to get to information that could be used to contact you.

> I've dragged a university research team to their ethical review board because they scraped GitHub emails to contact GitHub users for their research. They can't ethically do it, but technically there is nothing stopping them from extracting email addresses from repositories. You have a GitHub account linked, I'm sure they could have made the link there, scraped your email from your commits, and so build a database.

Comment: Thank you for moving the answers into the proper place.