# Survey Request From Software Performance, Analysis, and Reliability Lab (SPEAR) at Concordia University

Tags: discussion, survey, personal-data

Just received an email inviting me to participate in "A survey on your experience of using Stack Overflow" from "a group of software engineering and data analytics researchers from Concordia University and Queen’s University in Canada."

The intro to the survey states that "[t]he purpose of our research and this survey is to understand users’ satisfaction on Stack Overflow and potential ways to help improve the Stack Overflow community. In an effort to monitor and improve satisfaction, we would like to invite you to provide feedback on your experience of using Stack Overflow."

I'm assuming that this isn't an officially sanctioned survey - is it better to ignore it completely, reach out and suggest that they reword their intro to better fit SOs recommendations, or leave that to the SE team?

Comment: There have been previous cases of "surveys" being send to stack overflow users. None of those were facilitated, sponsored or endorsed by SE Inc. I would be surprised if this one was. If your profile includes enough data to make a good guess for your email-adres, they probably will.

Comment: Two things:  1)  You're not obligated to respond to any email you receive on any given day.  2) You *do* realize that what looks like a perfectly resolvable email address exists in your Git commits?  I just picked a repo at random and I can see an email address associated with your company, Hugo & Cat.  It's not a huge lift to get an email address from *that*, especially if you provide confidence that it's still valid (i.e. you state that that you still work at Hugo & Cat, so an email with that domain may still get to you).

Comment: other incidents: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364479/received-emailed-survey and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341939/request-to-participate-in-a-survey-based-on-stack-overflow-contribution

Comment: @Makoto Indeed, I know I'm not, and I also know that they're not following SOs guidelines as per rene's first link. I'm also aware that with a very limited amount of effort it's relatively easy to guess my personal email address or work one (I get enough recruiters through that to know ;)). Mostly just sad that they hadn't made the effort to personalize the email further with my name instead of addressing it to "software engineer"!

Comment: @TinyGiant:  I found that literally a day before you did...and yeah, that's pretty much the "not a huge lift" part of my comment above. /shrug

Comment: In the EU this would be personalized data and protected in its use by the [gdpr](https://eugdpr.org/) wich could have consequences for them to be used against EU citizens -you could start and ask for a  written agreement that they are allowed to use your personalzed data - followed up by a request to provide you with all informations about you they handle, where they got it from, etc. You can tell your local data protection authorities about them using/storing/handling your data without consent wich might result in fines.  just a question how much they annoy you +how much you want to annoy thm

Comment: Thank you all for missing the last part of the post, I'm aware that various email addresses of mine are indeed available online, and for all finding at least one of them. I'm also happy that the address that was used (not my work one) is easily guessable as in general I'd rather be contacted than not. I'll reword the final part of the question appropriately, as I was also aware that SO/SE don't give out data.

Comment: I just reported it as Phishing in gmail, as I have no reason to believe it's not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you've surmised, this survey (and many others like it) is not official or sanctioned by Stack Overflow.

These do happen from time to time with students seeking to collect data for a paper or some similar endeavor, and there are phishing attempts out there as well.

In any case, remember the golden rules:

- Do not open attachments or click on links that are not familiar to you.
- Before clicking on a link that does look familiar to you, remember to look at the actual address as reported by the browser. [https://facebook.com](https://google.com) <- This link to Google is trivially disguised as a link to Facebook.
- Stack Overflow will never ask for your password, login credentials, email, or other personally identifying information. Not the employees nor the moderators.

---

If you receive an email that you suspect is pretending to be an official one from Stack Overflow, please report it directly to the company using the [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact) form, the link for which is found at the footer of all pages on the site.

---

Relevant reading:

- [Received emailed survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364479/received-emailed-survey)
- [Request to participate in a survey based on Stack Overflow contribution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341939/request-to-participate-in-a-survey-based-on-stack-overflow-contribution)